# Yii function in layout file

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii and I'm new to it.
I have a default main.php layout file and i need to make some data extractions from DB and cookies. 
I've written 2 functions:

```
public function getRegionId() {
        if(isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies['region_id'])) {
            $sk = Yii::app()->request->cookies['region_id']->value;
            settype($sk,integer);
            return $sk;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public function regionId2region($id) {
        if(empty($id) or gettype($id)!=='integer') {
            return null;
        } else {
            $reg = Regions::model()->findAll(array(
                'condition'=>"alive=1 AND id=".$id,
            ));
            return $reg;
        }
    }
```

Now it is not working in any controller. My question is: is it possible to make functions in the layout file or is there a way to pass data to layout file (so that it displays in all controllers)?

Answer (score 0):

Move methods into Regions model and make it static. Or Create Helper class? contains just static methods.

```
class RegionHelper {
public static function getRegionId() {
        if(isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies['region_id'])) {
            return (int)$Yii::app()->request->cookies['region_id']->value;
        }
            return 1;
    }

    public static function regionId2region($id) {
        if(empty($id) or gettype($id)!=='integer') {
            return null;
        } else {
            $reg = Regions::model()->findAll(array(
                'condition'=>"alive=1 AND id=".$id,
            ));
            return $reg;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeforeAction` in your controller, like this:

```
protected function beforeAction($action) {

    //Define your variable here:
    public $yourVaribale;

    //do your logic and assign any value to variable

}
```

Now, you can use this variable in the view file:

view:

```
<h1><?php echo $this->yourVariable; ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your functions are located in the controller that calls the view, you could use the $this reference to access the function. Note the public access of the function.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    //   :
    //   :
    public function fullName($a,$b) {
        return $a.' '.$b;
    }
}
```

...and in your view ...

```
<h1>Test for <?php echo $this->fullName('Tom', 'Jones'); ?></h1>
```

If the function is in your model, there are a few choices.

```
class User extends Activerecord
{
    //   :
    //   :
    public function fullName($a,$b) {
        return $a.' '.$b;
    }
}
```

You could pass the model through the render function,

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    //   :
    //   :
    public function actionDisplayView {
        $userModel = User::model()->findByPK(1);
        $this->render('user_view', array('model' => $model));
    }
}
```

and directly call the function in the view.

```
< h1 >Test for <?php echo $model->fullName('Tom', 'Jones'); ?>< / h1 >
```

or, if you did not pass the function, you could call the function in the view (or helper classes). Watch the scope.

```
class User extends Activerecord
{
    //   :
    //   :
    // NOTE: You won't have access to $this.
    static public function fullName($a,$b) {
        return $a.' '.$b;
    }
}
```

and in the view

```
< h1 >Test for <?php echo User::fullName('Tom', 'Jones'); ?>< /h1 >
```